# How do I enable X-forwarding on OSX Lion?

Tags: macos, ssh

`ssh` works fine when when I log-in from OSX Lion to Lion or Lion to Ubuntu.

`ssh -X` (X-forwarding) works fine when I log-in from Lion to Ubuntu.

However, I can't seem to get `ssh -X` to work from Lion to Lion.

**How do I enable X forwarding on OSX Lion so I can run x applications from a remote machine?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

X11 forwarding is disabled per default for OS X SSH servers. Do the following on the **remote** machine:

```
sudo vi /etc/sshd_config
```

Search for the following line and remove the `#` sign at the beginning, change the `no` to `yes`, so that you end up with this:

```
X11Forwarding yes
```

Then write the file and quit `vim` by hitting `ESC` and typing `:wq` and hitting return.

Now restart the sshd process by typing:

```
killall -SIGHUP sshd
```

This will kill your ssh session, but after that you should be able to use `ssh -X` as usual. You may get warnings because of missing X authority files.

Comment: works great - tyvm